# how to display graphically layout in Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse

This error is create when I open graphically layout in eclipse? I make android apps..

> java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
>   Exception details are logged in Window > Show View > Error Log

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are probably using a Custom View that you created, or some error. Follow the instructions and check the Error Log.